# Error while trying to use strings while working with windows application forms

Tags: windows, string, forms, visual-c++

When creating a new class while working in a project that is based around windows application forms. I have a problem where string becomes unusable. I get errors the say things like

"a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type"

"IntelliSense: a function type involving a generic parameter cannot have an ellipsis parameter"

"IntelliSense: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "bsearch_s"(declared at line 426)"

Person.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;

ref class Person
{
public:
    Person(void);

    string name;   
};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Person::Person(void)
{
    name = "Bob";
}
```

If someone has a solution to this or a work around that isn't creating my own string class I would love to hear it as this has been bothering me for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String header in CLI C++ is already included in the System namespace.
String works as a pointer. Using the cap ^ handler

```
//This works:
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
void function()
{
String^ simpleStr = "Bob";
}
```